# Ricatti differential equation, there is one given solution but can't find Bernoulli equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

$$x^2y' + xy + x^2y^2 = 4$$

In this equation there are given one solution and this is

$$y=\frac{a}{x}$$

I think this is a Riccati equation and started solving by

$$y = v + \frac{a}{x}$$

and making derivation

$$y' = v' - \frac{a}{x^2}$$

So I ended up with this equation

$$v' = -v^2 -\frac{-v(2a+1)}{x} + \frac{4-a^2)}{x^2}$$

but I think this isn't a Bernoulli equation.

Is my starting point is wrong? Where can I go from this equation to find the general solution?

Comment: You should take $y=\dfrac1v+\dfrac{a}{x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Substituting $$y(x)=\frac{v(x)}{x}$$ then we get
$$\frac{dv(x)}{dx}=\frac{-v(x)^2+4}{x}$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: I find solution from there, but how can you find $y(x)=\frac{v(x)}{x}$ ? Isn't it a ricatti equation?

Comment: I have tried several substitutions and this works

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** With $y=\dfrac1v+\dfrac{a}{x}$ you find
$$v'+\dfrac3xv=1$$
which is a simple first order differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is to insert the class of proposed solutions to determine the constant $a$. In general there is only a finite number of such solutions. You should end up with $a^2=4$, $a=\pm 2$.

Choosing $a=2$,  your last equation reduces to the Bernoulli form 
$$v' = -v^2 +\frac{5v}{x}.$$

---

Additionally to the other proposed solution strategies, you could directly insert the parametrization $y=\frac{u'}u$ to get
$$
x^2u''+xu'=4u
$$
which is a Cauchy-Euler equation with basis solutions $x^2$ and $x^{-2}$, thus
$$
y(x)=\frac{2ax-2bx^{-3}}{ax^2+bx^{-2}}=\frac{2}x\cdot\frac{ax^4-b}{ax^4+b}.
$$